# What is the expansion of f(x) in ascending powers of x up to and including the term $x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-fractions

I did the beginning but am not able to expand it this is my work the question is linked to another part I will link that too.[image]

[image]

This is how a video extended the exact question but I don't know what is going on.[image]
Thank you very much I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Have you tried using the extended binomial theorem (for negative and fractional exponents)? If you do IB, it is listed in your formula booklet.

Comment: @Toby Mak i am doing a levels and I don't know how to continue?

Comment: Use the extended binomial theorem. Just search it up online.

Comment: @Toby Mak this question is a part of a past paper and he does solve it but I don't know what it is I will add an image and can you check if this is extended binomial theorem. Thank You I really appreciate it

Comment: @Sara you might want to revise chapter 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an A-Level Puremath-3 question, you have to apply the general binomial theorem, assuming your partial fraction decomposition was correct:


First set up for the  expansion by taking out factors from each of the terms so that they are in the general form $a^n(1+ax)^n$;

$$f(x)=(1-2x)^{-1}+3*2^{-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}-2*2^{-2}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-2}$$

$$f(x)=(1-2x)^{-1}+\frac{3}{2}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}-\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-2}$$

Next noting that the general binomial theorem expansion is of the form $$(1+ax)^n=1+(n)(ax)+\frac{(n)(n-1)(ax)^2}{2!}+\frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)(ax)^3}{3!}...$$

We can start to expand each term bearing in mind that we are limited up to and including the $x^2$ term

For the first term;

$$1+(-1)(-2x)+\frac{(-1)(-2)(-2x)^2}{2}= 1+2x+4x^2 $$

For the second term;
$$\frac{3}{2}\left[1+(-1)\left(-\frac{x}{2} \right) +\frac{(-1)(-2)(-\frac{x}{2})^2}{2} \right]=\frac{3}{2}\left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{4} \right)$$

For the third term
$$-\frac{1}{2}\left[1 +(-2)\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)+ \frac{(-2)(-3)\left(-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}{2}     \right]=-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+x+\frac{3x^2}{4}\right)$$

Finally adding all the terms up the final answer is

$$f(x)=2+\frac{9}{4}x+4x^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I really appreciate it but the mark scheme got $2+9x/4 +4x^2$ do you know how they got that?

Comment: @Sara My apologies, I seemed to have mistakenly read the third term as $-\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{x}{2})^{-1}$ I have corrected it now